# My code gives me random numbers around 10^-38 but I'm not using any random functions

Tags: fortran

I use Fortran 90 via Force 2.0, with a 64bits pc under windows 10.

I believe it may be a bug since my classmates use a very similar code and it works for them.

This is my code :

```
program integ
 implicit none
 real :: a_x , b_x , integ_1d, c
 a_x = 0
 b_x = 1
 c = integ_1d(a_x,b_x)
 write(*,*)c
 pause
end program integ

real function integ_1d (a_x , b_x)
 real :: x, f_x, pas
 real :: inte, a_x, b_x
 integer :: i
 integer , parameter :: npas=100
 pas=(b_x-a_x )/ npas
 inte =0.E0
 do i=0,npas-1
  x=a_x+( i*pas )
  inte=inte+ f_x
 end do
 integ_1d=inte*pas
end function integ_1d

real function f_x(x)
 real :: x
 f_x = x*x
end function f_x
```

It compiles without any issues but always gives me different values, around 10^-38. example :

```
1.75483065E-38
PAUSE
To resume execution, type go.  Other input will terminate the job.
```

or

```
1.16708418E-38
PAUSE
To resume execution, type go.  Other input will terminate the job.
```

with the exact same code, compiled on the same computer with the same fortran version.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: `inte=inte+ f_x` isn't a reference to the function `f_x` but the (undefined) local variable.   You probably mean something like `inte=inte+ f_x(x)`.

Comment: Thank you so much sir it now works perfectly !

Comment: Two tips:  check your compiler documentation, to find its option to force implicit none to always be applied.  with that, the compiler would have told you about the undefined local variable.   Also, putting your functions/subroutines in a module and "use"ing that module will catch a lot of errors.

Comment: @M.S.B., why would `implicit none` help the compiler detect reference to the undefined local (explicitly declared type) variable?  I agree with using `implicit none` but I don't see it as a panacea.

Comment: @francescalus You are correct, the local variable is explicitly typed, so implicit none would not help in this case.